# SQL Server: detect version and rename instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I appear to have 2 instances of SQL Server running on my machine;

- MSSQLSERVER
- SQLEXPRESS

How can I determine the version of each instance (2008/2012/2014/etc.) ?

How can I rename an instance of SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS > MSSSQLDATABASE) ?

Comment: you can run `SELECT @@VERSION` on these instances to get the version

Comment: Rename an instance equals uninstall + reinstall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your registry for this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ClientSetup\CurrentVersion
```

And for instance:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\YourInstance
```

To rename the instance you have **reinstall** it.

Also there is one script which I found [here](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/How-to-Rename-SQL-Server-Stand-Alone-Instance-After-Installing-SQL-Server.html):

```
Use Master
GO

sp_dropserver <old_name\instancename>
GO
sp_addserver <new_name\instancename>, local
GO
```

Also refer: **[Renaming a Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx)**